# Why does this regex work?

Tags: regex

I wanted to strip out the `(CDT)` from date time offset value. I wrote the simple **regex** below to do so and it works as originally expected but after writing it I'm left wondering why it works. Why doesn't the result stop at 2012?

**Original string:** `"Thu, 02 Aug 2012 07:42:02 -1525 (CDT)"`

**Regex:** `.*\d{4}`

**Result:** `"Thu, 02 Aug 2012 07:42:02 -1525"`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The quantifier `*` is greedy. This means it'll match as much as possible.

This is why `\d{4}` is matched to `1525` and `.*` matches to the characters before that.

If you use the lazy quantifier `*?` then it'll match with the smallest number of characters first before trying longer sequences. In that case it would let `\d{4}` match with `2012`.

Answer (score 5):

It works because `.*` is [greedy](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html).

What this implies, is that `.*` will match as much as a possible before doing anything else.

When the regex applies, `.*` matches the whole thing because it is greedy:

> **Thu, 02 Aug 2012 07:42:02 -1525 (CDT)**

then tries to match `\d{4}`, except that unfortunately, it doesn't match anything since it's at the end. The regex (the `.*` part) will therefore *backtrack* (go back and give back what is has previously matched) one character at a time and each time, check for `\d{4}`:

> **Thu, 02 Aug 2012 07:42:02 -1525 (CDT**)  [No match]
>
> **Thu, 02 Aug 2012 07:42:02 -1525 (CD**T)  [No match]
>
> **Thu, 02 Aug 2012 07:42:02 -1525 (C**DT)  [No match]
>
> **Thu, 02 Aug 2012 07:42:02 -1525 (**CDT)  [No match]
>
> **Thu, 02 Aug 2012 07:42:02 -1525** (CDT)  [No match]
>
> **Thu, 02 Aug 2012 07:42:02 -1525** (CDT)  [No match]
>
> ...
>
> **Thu, 02 Aug 2012 07:42:02 -**1525 (CDT)

At this point, it is able to match `\d{4}`, so that's what it will do:

> **Thu, 02 Aug 2012 07:42:02 -1525** (CDT)

And since there's nothing else in the regex, it will conclude here.

Answer (score 2):

The pattern `.*\d{4}` matches any sequence of zero or more characters (greedily) followed by 4 digits.

It works because it matches everything up to the last four digits in the string (`1525`) and ignores the remaining portion of the string.

Note that your pattern is a little dangerous. If your input was missing the timezone offset, the result would be significantly different:

- Input: `Thu, 02 Aug 2012 07:42:02`
- Output: `Thu, 02 Aug 2012`

Answer (score 0):

`.*` is *greedy* so it consumes as many characters as possible before finding the last possible four digits `\d{4}`.

In some regex engines (like perl) you can add `?` to specify a *non-greedy* match: `.*?\d{4}`, which should match 2012.

Answer (score 0):

The sybmol * is said to be "greedy". This means that it will match as many characters as possible of the preceding character before being forced to match the following token. 1525 is the last possible part that can satisfy \d{4} so the .* grabs everything up until 1525.

? usually works as a non-greedy token.

Answer (score 0):

regex engine steps:

```
matches                                | pattern | description
---------------------------------------+---------+-------------------------------
Thu, 02 Aug 2012 07:42:02 -1525 (CDT)  | .*      | match all possible characters
---------------------------------------+---------+-------------------------------
Thu, 02 Aug 2012 07:42:02 -1525 (CDT)  | \d{4}   | the RE doesn't find the 4 digits
---------------------------------------+---------+-------------------------------
Thu, 02 Aug 2012 07:42:02 -1525 (CDT   | \d{4}   | the RE backtracks char by char
---------------------------------------+---------+-------------------------------
Thu, 02 Aug 2012 07:42:02 -1525 (CD    | \d{4}   | to try to find the 4 digits
---------------------------------------+---------+-------------------------------
Thu, 02 Aug 2012 07:42:02 -1525 (C     | \d{4}   | no match
---------------------------------------+---------+-------------------------------

...

---------------------------------------+---------+-------------------------------
Thu, 02 Aug 2012 07:42:02 -1           | \d{4}   | no match
---------------------------------------+---------+-------------------------------
Thu, 02 Aug 2012 07:42:02 -1525        | \d{4}   | match
---------------------------------------+---------+-------------------------------
```